# risks of going with a very low reference voltage for a comparator

Tags: comparator

**Objective**

Digitization of pulses of `width` `10ns-150ns` repeating at a `rate` of `1Hz - 50Khz`

`Current` from photo diode of these pulses ranges from `50uA - 100mA`, so i want to do the I-V conversion just using a 50ohm resistor, to read voltage ranging from 2.5mV - 5V

**Approach :**

i want to avoid further amplification of the signal to avoid saturation and to maintain pulse width

i would just put a high speed comparator like [LMH7322](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh7322.pdf) after the 50ohm resistor and using a voltage reference of 1mV produced from a (1V LDO output and potential divider circuit)

**Problem Statement:**

my question is ,i did not see some one sensing low light current using this approach rather went for using a TIA, how safe is going with very low reference voltages like 0.5mV to 1mV ?, my intention is i can cover a large dynamic range using this technique

Comment: Maximum input offset voltage -8mV to 8mV, I dont think LMH7322 might work.

Comment: when i tested with its spice model, it worked , as the min being -8mV ? !

Comment: @kakeh Post the schematic, tested the circuit? with voltage 1.5 mV as reference?

Comment: @kakeh In the opamps spice models, the offset voltage is always 0. So it will always work (simulation places you in an ideal world). To simulate offset voltage, you need to place a small voltage source at one of the input, with a value between -8 and 8mV for LMH7322. Then you'll see big inaccuracies appearing. At these levels, what you need is a chopper opamp (lookup "ultra low offset voltage opamp").

Comment: IMO, you need an amplifier at input, only then use comparator.